# Why is the Autocomplete showing undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am getting `undefined` in the Autocomplete box even though it returns the results as expected. How can I address this issue?

```
import { Drawer, List, Typography, Switch, ListItem, ListItemText, ListItemSecondaryAction, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker } from 'react-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import iconRed from '../assets/leaflet_red.png';

const config = require('../config.json');

const popularityTypeIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: iconRed,
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [12, 41]
});

const drawerWidth = 400;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    marginTop: '63px',
  },
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    marginTop: 63,
    height: 'calc(100vh - 63px)',
  },
  quote: {
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(3),
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(15),
    fontFamily: 'cursive, serif',
    fontWeight: 500,
    fontSize: '1.2rem',
    color: '#555',
  },
}));

const Homepage = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [selectedMetro, setSelectedMetro] = useState('Richmond, VA');
  const [top5ZipCodes, setTop5ZipCodes] = useState([]);
  const [switchStates, setSwitchStates] = useState({});
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const [metros, setMetros] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedMetro) {
      fetch(`http://${config.server_host}:${config.server_port}/top_zip_codes_by_metro/?metro=${selectedMetro}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data?.length > 0) {
              setTop5ZipCodes(data);
              setSelectedMetro(selectedMetro);
              console.log("metro ==>", selectedMetro);
              console.log("data ==>", data);
              const initialSwitchStates = data.reduce((acc, zipCode) => {
              acc[zipCode.zipcode] = false;
              return acc;
            }, {});
            setSwitchStates(initialSwitchStates);
          }
          if (mapRef.current && data?.length > 0) {
            const bounds = L.latLngBounds(
              data.map(zipCode => [zipCode.lat, zipCode.lng])
            );
            mapRef.current.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: [50, 50] });
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error fetching top zip codes:', error);
        });
    }
  }, [selectedMetro]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = `http://${config.server_host}:${config.server_port}/all_metros`;
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(resData => setMetros(resData))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching metros:', error));
      console.log(metros)
  }, []);

  // const handleSelectedMetro = (event, data) => {
  //       console.log('Data:', data);
  //   if (data?.metro) {
  //     setSelectedMetro(data.metro)
  //   } else {
  //     setSelectedMetro('')
  //   }
  // };
const handleSelectedMetro = (event, data) => {
  console.log('Data:', data);
  if (data) {
    const selectedValue = typeof data === 'object' ? data.metro : data;
    setSelectedMetro(selectedValue);
  } else {
    setSelectedMetro('');
  }
};
  const handleSwitchToggle = (zipcode) => {
    setSwitchStates((prevSwitchStates) => ({
      ...prevSwitchStates,
      [zipcode]: !prevSwitchStates[zipcode],
    }));
  };

  // const handleTop5ZipCode = (event, data) => {
  //   console.log("data ==> ", data);
  //   if (data?.length > 0) {
  //     handleSelectedMetro(data);
  //     setTop5ZipCodes(data);
  //   }
  // }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <List>
          <ListItem>
            <Autocomplete
              id="metro"
              options={metros}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.metro}`}
              value={selectedMetro}
              onChange={handleSelectedMetro}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField {...params}
                  label="Type the desired metro"
                  variant="outlined"
                  sx={{ width: 360 }}
                />
              )}
              isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => 
                value === undefined || value === "" || option.metro === value || option.id === value.id
              }
            />
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem>
            {top5ZipCodes?.length > 0 && (
              <List>
                {top5ZipCodes?.map((element) => (
                  <ListItem key={element.zipcode}>
                    <ListItemText primary={
                      <Typography variant="h6">
                        {element.zipcode}
                      </Typography>} />
                    <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                      <Switch
                        checked={switchStates[element.zipcode] || false}
                        onChange={() => handleSwitchToggle(element.zipcode)}
                      />
                    </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                  </ListItem>
                ))}
              </List>
            )}
          </ListItem>
          <Typography variant="body1" className={classes.quote}>
            "Food is not just about sustenance; it's an expression of art, culture, and love that brings people together."
          </Typography>
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <MapContainer ref={mapRef} center={top5ZipCodes?.length > 0 ? [top5ZipCodes[0].lat, top5ZipCodes[0].lng] : [37.541290, -77.434769]} zoom={5} scrollWheelZoom={false} maxBoundsViscosity={0.7} style={{ height: '100%' }}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          {top5ZipCodes?.map((zipCode, index) => (
            <Marker key={index} position={[zipCode.lat, zipCode.lng]} icon={popularityTypeIcon}>
            </Marker>
          ))}
        </MapContainer>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Homepage;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspect:

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => 
  value === undefined || value === "" || option.metro === value || option.id === value.id
}
```

Firstly only one option should ever evaluate to true against this function but `value === undefined || value === ""` would apply universally to all options as it does not assert on the option argument.

Probably this should just be:

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => 
  option.metro === value
}
```

As well as this you should use `null` instead of `''` to indicate nothing has been selected.

Then you can detect this in the `getOptionLabel` to display empty string (or whatever you want) when nothing is selected:

```
getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.metro ?? ''}
```

In addition, since you are using the default value `Richmond, VA`, it must be certain that this entry appears in the list from the API. It might be best to conditionally render the autocomplete only once the list has finished loading.